# Java ternary operator - parameter order

Tags: java, operator-keyword, ternary

I just don't get what I'm doing wrong.
I'm trying to calculate the number of bytes needed for BCD. The formula is rather simple: number of digits, divided by two, rounded **up**.

So I tried this

```
int halfRoundedUp = isOddNumberOfDigits ? (numberOfDigitsInParameter/2) : (numberOfDigitsInParameter/2 + 1);
```

or

```
int halfRoundedUp = isOddNumberOfDigits ? (numberOfDigitsInParameter/2) : ((numberOfDigitsInParameter/2) + 1);
```

or, because it was logically more sound, originally this:

```
int halfRoundedUp = isOddNumberOfDigits ? (numberOfDigitsInParameter/2) : ((numberOfDigitsInParameter + 1) /2);
```

in several variations and bracketing. Lots of brackets. It keeps returning the wrong value when the flag is set; it should add +1 after halving, but it does not.

This workaround works just fine

```
int halfRoundedUp = numberOfDigitsInParameter/2;
if (isOddNumberOfDigits)
    halfRoundedUp ++;
```

but I'd like to understand what went wrong before. Can somebody explain why the above code snippets do not work as expected?

Comment: Glad that you got it solved but would appreciate if you would be little prudent in marking (OR calling) some mistake of ours as a bug. I would advise you to change the title here it gives wrong impression :)

Comment: With bug I meant one in my code. - I changed the title to make it more useful to others; if the title could use further improvement, please tell me so (suggestions welcome).

Comment: The _correct_ way to do this is just `(numberOfDigitsInParameter+1)/2`.  Truncating division is your friend if you know it's coming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your arguments in the wrong order. The general for of a ternary expression is:

```
condition ? return_if_true : return_if_false
```

If the number has an odd number of digits, you'd want to divide by two and add one, so you need to flip the arguments around:

```
int halfRoundedUp = isOddNumberOfDigits ? 
                    numberOfDigitsInParameter / 2  + 1 : 
                    numberOfDigitsInParameter / 2;
```

EDIT:
Even though the question was about the use of the ternary operator, I must say that personally, I'd just use [`java.util.Math.ceil(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil-double-):

```
// note the floating point division
int halfRoundedUp = Math.ceil(numberOfDigitsInParameter / 2.0);
```

Comment: Wouldn't using double require an (expensive) conversion back and forward between the two data types? - I have been looking for a Math.ceil() alike function with int, but didn't find any.